# Django Creating User Account Manually

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Django has a built in admin page where it comes with a feature to add/edit/remove user (and its authentication).

However, i need to create a custom form involving the following models

employee/models.py

```
# Stores profile details such as DoB, Martial Status, TFN and so on
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    MARTIAL_STATUS = (
        ('s', 'Single'),
        ('m', 'Married'),
        ('d', 'Divorced'),
        ('w', 'Widowed')
    )
    martial = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MARTIAL_STATUS, null=True)
    tfn = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
```

What i want to do is to have one form where user can enter information about the username, first_name, and so on along with all fields required in my models.

So far this is what i have done[image: django-form]

Notice how an account needs to be created first, before additional information (from different model) can be inserted

ps: i am using Django ver 1.6

Comment: Why don't you use directly a custom user instead of creating a OneToOneField relationship ?

Comment: @samidarko could you perhaps show me how? I refrain my self from creating a custom user as i need the user permission features in Django.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you need to create custom users for adding it to your profile form in admin site. Why don't you use django shell? For example:

where manage.py resides, open terminal/command prompt and type:

```
>>python manage.py shell

In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [2]: i=User(username="test")

In [3]: i.save()

In [4]: i.set_password('test')

In [5]: i.save()
```

You can use this username/password to login into site.

#### EDIT:

Assuming your admin url is like www.mysite.com/admin, you can access user directly using this like: www.mysite.com/admin/auth/user/add/. Also admin interface looks like this: [image].

And if you want to add email address and other data, you can press `save and continue editing` like below: [image]

This will lead you to updating user contents.[image]

If you want to create user not from admin site, then less painful way to implement user registration is using UserCreationForm.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^register/', CreateView.as_view(
            template_name='register.html',
            form_class=UserCreationForm,
            success_url='/'
    )),
    url('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

    # rest of your URLs as normal
)
```

you have to create a register.html here though like:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

details: http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/using-the-built-in-views-and-forms-for-new-user-registration-in-django.html

Comment: this needs to be done via an interface. Think of a registration page where the user can enter their desired username, email and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I usually start from [the documentation full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) then I adapt it for my needs. You keep the Django permissions but you also add some [custom permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions).

I don't know how far are you in your project but if you're just starting I recommend you to use [twoscoops templates](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project) or [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) of Daniel Greenfield. It also implements django all auth library which is very useful for social authentifcations.

Comment: i might go as you suggested. But at the moment i am trying to build my own 'admin' page for my apps. I am not sure how difficult it is to customize django out-of-the-box admin page visually (css and stuff). Twoscoops seems like a good template though..

Answer (score 0):

There should be `+` symbol near by `user` model dropdown box which eases the user to quick add, like the below one.

[image]

If the `user` model in registered with `admin` i think you could get access to create it on the fly.

#### OR

As [Ruddra's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24750849/810217) above answer, you have create all user profiles, then you can fillup the form in straight manner.